# Basis for Solution Space of Differential Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Quick question for my differential equations and linear algebra homework. Say we have a differential equation that has the general solution 
$$
y = c_1e^{-2x} + c_2e^{-2x}
$$ where $c1$, $c2$ are arbitrary constants.

I need to find the basis for this. If the exponents had opposite signs, the basis would just be:
$$
\{e^{-2x},\ e^{2x}\}
$$
But since they are the same, and the exponent has an algebraic multiplicity of $2$, I'm not quite sure of the proper way to state the basis. I could see the basis being

1. $\{e^{-2x}\}$, or
2. $\{e^{-2x},\ e^{-2x}\}$, or even
3. $\{0,\ e^{-2x}\}$.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Cases 2. and 3. can never be a basis since the functions **are dependent**. The case 1. has too few vectors for a second order DE, thus, no basis either. I would recommend you to have a good look at the definition of a basis and think over what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Notice, if the roots are equal then the general solution of differential equation: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+4x\frac{dy}{dx}+4x^2y=0$  is given as  $$y=(c_1+xc_2)e^{-2x}$$

while the basis, $e^{-2x}$ & $e^{2x}$ shows that roots are distinct of differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-4x^2y=0$ whose general solution is given as $$y=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-2x}$$

Comment: So you're saying y=c1e^2x+c2e^2x would have a basis of just {e^2x}, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Awesome, one last thing. Why is the basis of the equation just {e^2x} when it is multiplied by more than just an arbitrary constant on one side (i.e. x)?